# На чем лучше организовать подобный функционал?

Tags: битрикс, httpbackend

Есть сайт: http://vmeste.mosreg.ru/Map# Хотелось бы сделать нечто похожее для своего города, подскажите, что лучше, использовать уже готовые системы управления, или самописное решение? + Интересует реализация данного решения на 1с Битрикс, реально ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс вполне подходит для создания такого сайта. Использование его как CMS или CMF позволит достаточно сильно сократить время разработки

Answer (score 0):

Что вы подразумеваете под "самописное" - хотите сами написать или open source? Да, на битриксе это сделать реально. Делать нужно на том, на чем удобно ну или привыкли к чему то. Также зависит от разработчика.